# Mediaquery - max-width issue

Tags: css

I want to to remove an html element by display:none . When the screen width is less than 500px ;

```css
@media (max-width:500px)
  {
    button { display:none};
    }
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

The problem is , the button disappears when the screen is less than 300px
not than 500px

Comment: Its working fine in my FF `51.0.1`.

Comment: tried `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {` ?

Comment: I am using google choome

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine

https://jsfiddle.net/8k2w28m6/

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px)
```

Comment: Robbin, we need max-device-width here. Your solution appears to work only because the browser window is maximalized and the width is close to the device width.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cut bread with a meat knife. You want to apply a rule in a case the device width is smaller than a given width, yet, your rule applies to `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`. The fix should be something like:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:500px)
  {
    button { display:none};
    }

<button>Test</button>
```